# Циклический сдвиг списка на N элементов вправо

Tags: python

Мне надо сдвинуть список на N элементов вправо.
Для этого я сначала перемещаю элементы из конца в начало (первый цикл `for`), а потом сортирую другую половину списка (второй цикл `for`). Не могу понять, почему сортировка не происходит.

**Входные данные:**

6 // кол-во элементов массива

1 2 3 4 5 6 // элементы массива

2 // кол-во элементов на которое надо сдвинуть

**Выходные данные:**

5 6 1 2 3 4 5

**Мой код:**

```
n = int(input())
a = input().split()
x = int(input())
for i in range(x):
    temp = a[i]
    a[i] = a[n - x + i]
    a[n - x + i] = temp
for i in range(x, n - 1):
    for j in range(x, n - i - 1):
        if a[j] > a[j + 1]:
            temp = a[j]
            a[j] = a[j + 1]
            a[j + 1] = temp
print(*a)
```

Comment: Для циклического сдвига массива существует очень простой и эффективный алгоритм, через reverse подмассивов. [Тут](https://pastebin.com/kbM1brvm) он описан в самом начале (Алгоритм #3) / Код, использующий функцию переворота, оказывается эффективным и
малотребовательным к памяти, и настолько короток и прост,
что при его реализации сложно ошибиться

Comment: `5 6 1 2 3 4 5` - почему пятёрка осталась в конце списка? Разве не должно быть `5 6 1 2 3 4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение с помощью слайсов.

```
length = int(input())
lst = list(map(int, input().split()))
shift = int(input())

lst = lst[-shift:] + lst[:-shift]

print(lst)
```

**Input**

```
10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
4
```

**Output**

```
[7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в это строке:

```
a = input().split()
```

Когда вы вводите `1 2 3 4 5 6`, переменная а будет иметь значение `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']`.

Так как это строка. Чтобы это исправить воспользуйтесь функцией map:

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Эта функция применит операцию int к каждому элементу списка input().split(). А функция list преобразует результат в список.